# Why my ASP.NET application design can vary with system to system? How to achieve this?

Tags: asp.net

i developed one asp.net application.i published the application in iis server.then by using that url i am testing the application in my system the design is coming fine.But in other systems the design is vary.both the systems are having IE8 Browser and both are same versions.

why the designing is vary can u pls let me know.

and also button styles all are different changing in system to system.

Comment: What differences you see? Any screenshots?

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide an answer.  You should ask about a specific difference and provide a screen shot of both systems (correct/incorrect) along with the relevant html/css.

Answer (score -1):

As regards button styles, they do change from "system" to "system" if by system you mean computer and operating system. Unless you've styled your buttons is a specific way that does not rely on operating system defaults/styles, they will appear different.

Can you be more specific about the other variances you see?

Comment: Please add this as a comment as this does not "Answer" the OPs question.

Comment: It does answer his question about buttons looking different. Maybe the other variances he's seeing are related.

Comment: ..What variances? What related?